# Обособляется ли слово "действительно"?

Tags: пунктуация

В "Тотальном диктанте" есть такая фраза:  «Если страна под названием Россия вдруг обнаружит, что она потеряла существенную часть своей территории и значительную долю своего населения, можно будет сказать, что в начале нулевых нам, ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО, было ни до чего и что в эти годы мы занимались более важными делами, чем сохранение государственности, национальной идентичности и территориальной целостности».

Вопрос 1.Я сомневаюсь в том,  что в этом тексте слово "действительно" является вводным.

Вопрос 2. Я сомневаюсь в том, что текст может допускать двойное решение. Если это имеет место, то перед нами не самый лучший текст с неясно выраженным содержанием.

ОТВЕТ 1.  Слово "действительно" имеет два значения: уверенность в сказанном (обычно наречие в роли обстоятельства) и подтверждение ранее сказанного (только вводное слово).  Разные оттенки смысла требуют разной структуры предложения,  поэтому вводное слово "действительно" обычно стоит в начале предложения. 
Сравнить:Действительно, на другой день к обеду все сборы были кончены. Но: Он действительно хорошо знает свой предмет.
Мне кажется, что смысл ПИСЬМЕННОГО текста (даже оттенки смысла) не должны зависеть от ДИКТОРА, да и логическим ударением выделить это слово в середине текста трудно (структура не позволяет. Поэтому в приведенном отрывке явное смысловое значение уверенности в середине предложения может иметь только обстоятельство.

ОТВЕТ 2. Мне не очень нравятся тексты Пелевина.  Возможно, в его произведениях  есть яркие и интересные мысли, но они не отличаются безукоризненной формой изложения. Поэтому странно, что именно на примере его произведения проверялась массовая грамотность россиян. Лучше бы взяли, например, Бунина, там уж точно каждая запятая на своем  месте, и никаких факультативных знаков.
Для примера рассмотрим предложение: «Сейчас это понять непросто (?) в конечном счете время покажет». Возможны три варианта (запятая, тире, двоеточие), и все нехороши. Мысль понятная, а формы нечитаемые. Перечислительная интонация с запятой не подходит – нет равновесия отдельных частей при перечислении.  При двоеточии или тире первая часть звучит нормально, а  сочетание «в конечном счете» во  второй части никак  не читается. Хочется что-то переделать, например: Сейчас это понять  непросто, в конечном счете –  время  покажет. Тире в неполном предложении ставится на месте пропущенного дополнения «это».

ОТВЕТ 3.К сожалению, я не знала о "тотальных" задачах диктанта (хотелось бы их прояснить). Идея предыдущего высказывания была такая: трудно писать текст, в котором каждая вторая запятая факультативная. Это мысли должны быть многомерными, а форме следует однозначно их выражать. И насчет "нравится-не нравится". Я тоже за "разные жанры" в литературе, лишь бы они были "хорошими". Мне нравится современная экспрессия в языке, но форма речи для таких текстов сложнее, и не все умело ею пользуются. А это уже серьезная проблема: нам хочется выразить нечто космическое, то есть задача содержания осложняется, а умение писать (хотя бы на прежнем, далеко не лучшем уровне) стремительно падает. Владеть формой в совершенстве хорошо бы поучиться у "мертвых классиков", и уже потом блистать талантом в новых сферах.

Comment: А при чём тут Пелевин, если текст написан Захаром Прилепиным? Тотальный диктант - это текст, написанный специально для проекта, естественно ни какой мёртвый классик, каким бы авторитетным он не был, автором текста для тотального диктанта быть не может. А по поводу нравиться не нравится,  это уже дело вкуса. Очень хорошо, что не все писатели пишут как Бунин.

Comment: Цели тотального диктанта:

1. Привлечь внимание СМИ и общества к проблеме грамотности;

2. Дать возможность всем желающим проверить свою грамотность в ходе добровольного диктанта;

3. Повысить уровень грамотности участников с помощью «пятиминуток ликбеза» и разбора ошибок;

4. Повысить статус владения языковыми навыками, распространить моду на грамотность.

Для привлечения СМИ наличие живого автора, специально написавшего текст для проекта, немаловажно. Ещё это исключит вероятность того, что кто-то этот текст уже видел. Бунин "чёрт" через "о" писал, но это написание для нас уже не актуально.

Answer (score 6):

Согласна с Вами в том, что слово *действительно* может как быть вводным, так и не быть таковым. Но если диктант был на самом деле диктантом (я ни разу в таком не участвовала), то диктор должен был читать выразительно, чтобы можно было услышать логическое ударение на слове, если оно не является вводным. Мне  такой вариант нравится больше.

Answer (score 0):

Его читал сам Прилепин, читал с паузами, как вводное. Но факультативные знаки препинания там всё же есть:

1. Допустимо: 1) …немалое количество людей самого разного возраста – в первую очередь молодых; 2) …немалое количество людей самого разного возраста, в первую очередь – молодых.
2. Допустимо: 1) Сейчас это понять непросто: в конечном счете время покажет; 2) Сейчас это понять непросто – в конечном счете время покажет.
3. Допустимо: сетования на безразличие граждан к судьбе Родины были, по меньшей мере, беспочвенны...
4. Допустимо: Я вспоминаю своих стариков – как красивы они были...
5. Допустимо: 1) И еще – как счастливы были...; 2) ...счастливы были, что мы – дети и внуки их – путаемся среди них...
6. Допустимо: ...стали, как минимум, признаком дурного тона.

   ---