# Вы, действительно, герои! Нужно ли обособление?

Tags: вводные-слова

Вы, действительно, герои! Необходимо ли обособлять «действительно»?

Comment: См. ответы: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/91/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5 и http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26073/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE

Answer (score 1):

**Из словаря:**

**ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО**. **I. нареч.** В действительности, подлинно, в самом деле. Он д. очень устал. **II. вводн. сл**. Подтверждает чью-л. мысль, выражает уверенность в чём-л. На этот раз, д., он прав. **III. частица**. Употр. для выражения утверждения; да, верно. Он так сказал? - Д.

**1) Наречие:** Это очень смелый поступок, и вы **действИтельно** герои!

**2) Вводное слово** (обычно в начале предложения для подтверждения ранее высказанного суждения): Действительно, такой поступок можно назвать геройским.

Для окончательного суждения желательно иметь полный текст.